# Strange Date String to Date

Tags: python, date

I got some date online, and it's date string is pretty strange to me, for example:

'/Date(1506700800000)/'

I do not know how to parse, the integer string is not real time stamp, if I parse is in python using

```
time_stamp = "1506700800000"
datetime.fromtimestamp(int(time_stamp)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

I got wrong year, so I assume that's not a legal time stamp

As i am using Visual Studio to debug Python code, the Visual Studio watch windows show me the right time to be : 09/29/2017 16:00:00 automatically.

But I have no idea how VS does this conversion. I search on Google for long time but still not able to solve this problem, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: That looks like epoch time, seconds elapsed since January 1, 1970.

Comment: @ako That is milliseconds, not seconds.

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
import datetime
ms="1506700800000"
datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(int(ms)/1000.0)
#if you want in string
datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(int(ms)/1000.0).strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

output

```
datetime.datetime(2017, 9, 29, 21, 30)
```

output in string
     2017-09-29 21:30:00

Comment: Yeah, that will gives the right year-month-day, but time seems wrong, that can be the time zone issue. Thanks  a lot!

Comment: OK, I will do it,  at this point I do not see the "mark a an answer" button , may be it will show up later. Thanks!